# Didn't find class "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nfc, slf4j

i am getting error in `Caused by   "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory"`.
i have attached  `slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar` lib . but i dont know what is problem.
please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download Zip file from http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/slf4j/slf4j.jar.zip then copy jar file to your lib folder of your project after extract that zip file

Comment: hey error for LoggerFactory Solved but now for ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext : Didn't find class "org.slf4j.LoggerContext"

Comment: Download and copy jar to your lib folder after extract zip file from : http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/logback-classic/logback-classic.jar.zip

Comment: i have solved this by downloading version slf4j.1,7.7.jar

Comment: I solved this myself by downloading slf4j-1.7.25.zip and adding slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar to my libs folder